「こんな考えの私の半生なんて君たちには興味ないだろうかな」

こんな考えの私の半生なんて君たちには興味ないだろうかな(Clip on YouTube)

This line had me scratching my head. Unless I am hearing it wrong, it seems the subject of the sentence which is the agent that holds the interest is marked by 格助詞「に」.  I think the usual construction is A（人）はB（物・人）に興味がある・ない. And I have never come across a sentence like this one at issue where the subject as opposed to the object is marked by に. Why is it the case here? I thought of cases where に marks the subject that holds/takes/bears responsibility or the blame. 「私には責任がある」「君には非がない」. Is this related?

When you say something like 私には夢がある, the subject is not 私 but 夢, even if the sentence is typically translated as "I have a dream". The literal translation is "Dream exists at me", with "dream" as the subject.
Likewise, when you say "彼は音楽に興味がある" or "私の半生なんて君たちには興味(が)ない", the subject is always 興味, not 彼 or 君たち. The は-marked argument is called a topic. The literal translation of the former is "As for him, interest exists towards music".
Confusingly, に is a versatile particle which acts like both "to/towards/against" (destination/target marker) and "in/at/around" (location marker, when combined with ある/ない). In the context of 興味がある, this means に can mark either the target of interest and the location (owner) of interest. This is why a sentence like 彼女には興味がある is ambiguous; while it typically means "[I am] interested in her", it sometimes means "She is interested [in it]" depending on the context. Either way, the subject is 興味.
Similarly, 彼女に興味がある人 typically means "the person who is interested in her", but 彼女に興味がある物 means "things in which she is interested".
As a last resort, expressions like にとって, によって and に対して can be used to narrow down the function of に:

彼女に対して興味がある人
the person who is interested in her
彼女にとって興味がある人
the person whom she is interested in

However, these are seldom needed in reality in short sentences.

I guess I haven't encountered the case you discuss where the location of interest is marked by に. I understand you often talk about double-subject sentences in your answers. I wonder why you seem to avoid that interpretation in this answer. Is there a syntactic difference between 彼は音楽に興味がある and 象は鼻が長い? Note: I understand not everybody subscribes to the double-subject interpretation which was proposed and championed by linguists like 大槻文彦 and 橋本進吉.  Personally I consider it sloppy and outdated but it seems you've mentioned it many times in your answers so I'm curious why it doesn't apply here

@desmo So-called "double-subject" is a convenient term to describe sentences like 象は鼻が長い, but it may not be a formal grammatical structure when you analyze Japanese in its own right (that's why I usually enclose the term in double quotes). If asked what the subject of 象は鼻が長い is, I'll say it's 鼻 simply because it's marked with が.

You can google 自分に興味があること to see many examples where に marks the "location" of 興味.
